# execute external method python in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, plone

I have this:

```
<ul tal:repeat="record context/all_users">
  <li tal:content="record/name"></li>
</ul>
```

and this external method:`tal:content="python:context.getresource('')"`
I wanto to put the `element(name)`  that I will select from the list in the external method

But I am not able to do this.

I tought to use `<tal:define-macro:"">` for each element in the list:

```
<ul tal:repeat="record context/all_users">
  <div tal:define-macro="element">
    <a href="">
      <li tal:content="record/name"></li>
    </a>
  </div>
</ul>
```

but itis not correct.I don't know how to declare the macro in the dynam list and how to put the value in the external method.

I tried this:

```
function getWord(field) {
  var word = field.innerHTML;

  var t = python:context.getresource(word)
}
```

but it doesn't work too.

Comment: I removed your phptal tag which is probably going to upset lots of people. Could you rephrase your question to be a question?

Comment: This is still super confusing. How are you going to select? Do you perhaps need a <select> instead of a <ul>? Or perhaps you want to pass the tal:repeat item to an external method?

Comment: I have the list like :name1,name2,name3...I select name1.Now I want to pass name like parameter of the external method like: python:context.getId(name1)...I hope now you can understand me

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you won't get this to work: TAL is executed server-side, before the page is shipped to the user, before any javascript is handled or the user selects anything. You'll need to look in a vaguely AJAXy direction.

Comment: @uto: If you resolved your problem, you can answer your own question, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass dynamic data from PYthon to Javascript here is a technique how to do it:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates_css_and_javascripts/javascript.html#passing-dynamic-settings-to-javascripts